# Error: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown on my C# win form program with firebird database and DevExpress

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, firebird, dispose

I am having trouble with system.outofmemoryexception on my C# win application. I don't know the cause of the error. The computer memory is not freeing.
I am using visual studio 2017 and devexpress 2017 with Firebird 3 as my database.

here is a sample of my database procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE APP_INSERT(
  WORKXP_PK INTEGER,
  EMP_PK INTEGER,
  APP_FRONT BLOB,
  APP_BACK BLOB,
  USER_PK SMALLINT,
  APP_UPDATETIME TIMESTAMP)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO APPOINTMENT (
    WORKXP_PK,
    EMP_PK,
    APP_FRONT,
    APP_BACK,
    USER_PK,
    APP_UPDATETIME)
  VALUES (
    :WORKXP_PK,
    :EMP_PK,
    :APP_FRONT,
    :APP_BACK,
    :USER_PK,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE APP_UPDATE(
  APP_FRONT BLOB,
  APP_BACK BLOB,
  USER_PK SMALLINT,
  APP_UPDATETIME TIMESTAMP,
  WORKXP_PK INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE APPOINTMENT
  SET
    APP_FRONT = :APP_FRONT,
    APP_BACK = :APP_BACK,
    USER_PK = :USER_PK,
    APP_UPDATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  WHERE
    (WORKXP_PK = :WORKXP_PK);
END;
```

And here is a sample of my c# class

```
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DepEdZDSMS.Class
{
    class ClsAppointmntPic : IDisposable
    {
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                FirebirdService.Close();
            }
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

         public MemoryStream APP_FRONT { get; set; }
         public MemoryStream APP_BACK { get; set; }
  public void UpdateAppImage()
         {
             byte[] x = null; //front image
             byte[] y = null; //back image
             try
             {
                 var adder = new FbConnection(ClsConnectionImages.FirebirdSQL);
                 var fbcmd = new FbCommand("APP_UPDATE", adder)
                 {
                     CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                 };

                 if (APP_FRONT != null) x = APP_FRONT.ToArray();
                 fbcmd.Parameters.Add("@APP_FRONT", FbDbType.Binary).Value = x;
                 if (APP_BACK != null) y = APP_BACK.ToArray();
                 fbcmd.Parameters.Add("@APP_BACK", FbDbType.Binary).Value = y;
                 fbcmd.Parameters.Add("@USER_PK", FbDbType.SmallInt).Value = ClsEmployee.USER_PK;
                 fbcmd.Parameters.Add("@APP_UPDATETIME", FbDbType.VarChar).Value = EventTimestamp;
                 fbcmd.Parameters.Add("@WORKXP_PK", FbDbType.VarChar).Value = ClsEmployee.UpdateHandler2;
                 fbcmd.Connection.Open();
                 fbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 fbcmd.Connection.Close();
             }
             catch (Exception errorcode)
             {
                 XtraMessageBox.Show(String.Format("Error in connection: {0}. Saving failed.", errorcode.Message), @"Server Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
             }
         }

        public void SaveAppImage() //122
        {
            byte[] x = null; //front image
            byte[] y = null; //back image

            try
            {
                var adder = new FbConnection(ClsConnectionImages.FirebirdSQL);
                var fbcmd = new FbCommand("APP_INSERT", adder)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                };
                fbcmd.Parameters.Add("@WORKXP_PK", FbDbType.VarChar).Value = ClsEmployee.UpdateHandler2;
                fbcmd.Parameters.Add("@EMP_PK", FbDbType.VarChar).Value = ClsEmployee.UpdateHandler;
                if (APP_FRONT != null) x = APP_FRONT.ToArray();
                fbcmd.Parameters.Add("@APP_FRONT", FbDbType.Binary).Value = x;
                if (APP_BACK != null) y = APP_BACK.ToArray();
                fbcmd.Parameters.Add("@APP_BACK", FbDbType.Binary).Value = y;
                fbcmd.Parameters.Add("@USER_PK", FbDbType.SmallInt).Value = ClsEmployee.USER_PK;
                fbcmd.Parameters.Add("@APP_UPDATETIME", FbDbType.VarChar).Value = EventTimestamp;

                fbcmd.Connection.Open();
                fbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                fbcmd.Connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception errorcode)
            {
                XtraMessageBox.Show(String.Format("Error in connection: {0}. Saving failed.", errorcode.Message), @"Server Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }

        public ClsAppointmntPic(int refID)
        {
            try
            {
                var app = new ClsAppointmntPic();
                var x = new DataSet();
                var y = new FbDataAdapter();

                var f = new FbCommand("IMAGE_APPOINTMENT", FirebirdService);

                f.Parameters.Add("@X", FbDbType.Integer).Value = refID;

                f.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                y.SelectCommand = f;
                y.Fill(x, "APPOINTMENT");

                if (x.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    var fx = x.Tables[0].Rows[0];

                    if (!fx["APP_FRONT"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                    {
                        var i = (byte[])fx["APP_FRONT"];
                        var fx2 = new MemoryStream(i);
                        APP_FRONT = fx2;
                    }
                    if (!fx["APP_BACK"].Equals(DBNull.Value))
                    {
                        var j = (byte[])fx["APP_BACK"];
                        var fx2 = new MemoryStream(j);
                        APP_BACK = fx2;
                    }
                }
                app.FirebirdService.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                XtraMessageBox.Show(@"Error: " + e.Message, @"DepEdZDSUIS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

            }
        }


        public ClsAppointmntPic()
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
    }


        private void Openconnection()
        {
            if (FirebirdService.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                FirebirdService.Close();
            }
            FirebirdService.Open();
        }

        private void Closeconnection()
        {
            FirebirdService.Close();
        }
        private static readonly string Firebird = ClsConnectionImages.FirebirdSQL;
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private readonly FbConnection FirebirdService = new FbConnection(Firebird);
    }
}
```

and also I used  public static string and int frequently and some arrays

```
public static int sdsapprove_ref = 0;

public static string sdsapprove_word = "";

public static string[] reasonReg = new string[] { "Deceased", "Promoted to", "Retired", "Resigned", 
                    "Transferred to"};
```

in my main view form I use this code in displaying data

```
private void GetWorkXPList()
        {
            picAppFront.Image = Properties.Resources.no_image;
            picAppBack.Image = Properties.Resources.no_image;
            ClsEmployee.UpdateHandler2 = "0";
            gridControl2.DataSource = ClsEmployee.WorkXP_SrvcRcrdListing();
            gridView2.OptionsSelection.InvertSelection = false;
            gridView2.OptionsSelection.EnableAppearanceFocusedCell = false;
            gridView2.OptionsSelection.EnableAppearanceFocusedRow = true;

        }

 public void GetAppointmentImage()
        {
            int getID = Convert.ToInt32(ClsEmployee.UpdateHandler2);

            var f = new ClsAppointmntPic(getID);

            if (f.APP_FRONT != null)
            {
                var i = new Bitmap(f.APP_FRONT);
                picAppFront.Image = i;
            }
            else
            {
                picAppFront.Image = Properties.Resources.no_image;
            }

            if (f.APP_BACK != null)
            {
                var j = new Bitmap(f.APP_BACK);
                picAppBack.Image = j;
            }
            else
            {
                picAppBack.Image = Properties.Resources.no_image;
            }
        }
```

and in my save/update form, i use this codes when saving and editing

```
private void UpdateWorXP()
        {
            var adder = new ClsEmployee()
            {
                WORKXP_DATEFROM = dateFrom.Text,
                WORKXP_DATETO = dateTo.Text,
                WORKXP_PRESENT = ifPresent,
                WORKXP_POSITION = txtPosition.Text,
                WORKXP_ABBR = txtAbb.Text,
                WORKXP_ITMENUM = txtItemNo.Text,
                WORKXP_AGENCY = txtAgency.Text,
                WORKXP_STATION = txtStation.Text,
                WORKXP_BRANCH = txtBranch.Text,
                WORKXP_SLRYGRD = txtSG.Text,
                WORKXP_INCRMNT = cboxIncrmnt.Text,
                WORKXP_SALARYANN = txtAnnual.Text,
                WORKXP_SALARYMON = txtMonthly.Text,
                WORKXP_STATUS = cboxStatus.Text,
                WORKXP_GOVORPRIV = cboxGov.Text,
                WORKXP_CAUSE = cboxCause.Text,
                WORKXP_AMOUNT = Convert.ToDecimal(txtAmount.Text),
            };
            adder.EditWorkXP();
            adder.UpdateLog();
            //UpdateEmpLatestApp();
            XtraMessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated.", "Update ",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            ClsEmployee.UpdateHandler2 = "0";
            switch (ClsArray.Reference)
            {
                case 1:
                    obj1.loaddata();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    obj2.loaddata();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    obj3.loaddata2();
                    break;
            }
            this.Close();
        }
        private void AddNewWorkXP()
        {
            var adder = new ClsEmployee()
            {
                WORKXP_DATEFROM = dateFrom.Text,
                WORKXP_DATETO = dateTo.Text,
                WORKXP_PRESENT = ifPresent,
                WORKXP_POSITION = txtPosition.Text,
                WORKXP_ABBR = txtAbb.Text,
                WORKXP_ITMENUM = txtItemNo.Text,
                WORKXP_AGENCY = txtAgency.Text,
                WORKXP_STATION = txtStation.Text,
                WORKXP_BRANCH = txtBranch.Text,
                WORKXP_SLRYGRD = txtSG.Text,
                WORKXP_INCRMNT = cboxIncrmnt.Text,
                WORKXP_SALARYANN = txtAnnual.Text,
                WORKXP_SALARYMON = txtMonthly.Text,
                WORKXP_STATUS = cboxStatus.Text,
                WORKXP_GOVORPRIV = cboxGov.Text,
                WORKXP_CAUSE = cboxCause.Text,
                WORKXP_AMOUNT = Convert.ToDecimal(txtAmount.Text),
            };
            adder.SaveWorkXP();
            adder.UpdateLog();
            //UpdateEmpLatestApp();
            XtraMessageBox.Show("Successfully Saved.", "Save ",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            ClsEmployee.UpdateHandler2 = "0";
            switch (ClsArray.Reference)
            {
                case 1:
                    obj1.loaddata();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    obj2.loaddata();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    obj3.loaddata2();
                    break;
            }
            this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: At which line of code was it thrown? Also remove catch (Exception e) - it makes harder to DEBUG and senseless in release

Comment: Why are you calling `GC.SuppressFinalize` here?

Comment: @DavidG because it saves the GC from unnecessary work if you have manually handled the resources.

Comment: @Crowcoder It does that if there is a finalizer, but this code doesn't have a finalizer.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yeah, I know how it works, but I'm asking why OP put it in there. The class isn't disposing of the objects it creates manually...

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, but generally only if you have a finaliser.

Comment: Without any profiler or debug info this will be hard to solve. But it's strange that each ClsAppointmntPic holds  1 FbConnection . How many will you have alive at peak?

Comment: @DavidG so, [Jon Skeet says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605412/why-should-we-call-suppressfinalize-when-we-dont-have-a-destructor) it is not necesary, but Bill Wagner (*Effective c#*) says to suppress finalize anyway in case derived classes add unmanaged resources. So I'm still on the fence.

Comment: Re the Disposable pattern: this is mostly outdated guidance, we shouldn't deal with unmanaged at all (see SafeHandle) and any derived class that does ought to be shot. But formally, make ClsAppointmntPic `sealed` and you can drastically reduce the pattern.

Comment: @EugeneGorbovoy when saving and updating record. When I close the form still the memory wont reduce.