# Is this how to "Implement IDisposable correctly"?

Tags: c#, code-analysis, dispose, idisposable, suppressfinalize

I ran Code Analysis on one of my projects, and it gave me two finger wags, namely:

*CA1063 Implement IDisposable correctly Provide an overridable implementation of Dispose(bool) on 'UserStore' or mark the type as sealed. A call to Dispose(false) should only clean up native resources. A call to Dispose(true) should clean up both managed and native resources.*

...on this line of  code:

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<User>, IUserPasswordStore<User>,  IUserClaimStore<User>
```

...and this:

*CA1063 Implement IDisposable correctly Modify 'UserStore.Dispose()' so that it calls Dispose(true), then calls GC.SuppressFinalize on the current object instance ('this' or 'Me' in Visual Basic), and then returns.*

...on my empty Dispose:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    //
}
```

Can I assassinate two avians with one petrified dirtclod by doing this:

```
public override void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

? Is that what it's suggesting?

### UPDATE

To answer my question (sort of), apparently not - I figured I'd just add the code and see if the Code Analysis would then feed back the yearned-for "'NRBQ.API.UserStore.Dispose()': no suitable method found to override"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605466/idisposable-gc-suppressfinalizethis-location?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605412/why-should-we-call-suppressfinalize-when-we-dont-have-a-destructor and there is also documentation on msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface?rq=1 my favorite ))